# Duplicating wide-character string

Tags: c++, linux, windows, widechar, wchar

I am trying to create an application in which I have a function where I am trying to duplicate a wide character string. I am currently using `_wcsdup()`, since it is a Windows application and everything is working fine for me. But I need to create a multi-platform function, so `_wcsdup()` (which is a Windows function) will not work out for me.

Now, my code looks something like this:

```
wchar_t* out = _wcsdup(wstring.str().c_str());
```

where `wstring` is a string stream.

Now, I am looking for a common function for both Windows and Linux to make this function work properly.

Comment: Why you don't use `std::copy`?

Comment: Why not `std::wstring out = wstring.str();`?

Comment: btw, `wstring` is a terrible name for a variable given that it is the same as the Standard Library type `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Galik the OP did say: "*where wstring is a string stream*"

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Is there an overload of `std::copy` that returns a `wchar_t *` string, that can later be released by `free`?

Comment: @Kaz `std::copy()` doesn't allocate anything, so there is nothing to free.  It merely copies data from one buffer to another.  It is your responsibility to allocate and free those buffers as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I don't understand the first comment; how will `std::copy` solve the problem of "I have a C++ `wstring`. The API I'm using needs a `wchar_t *` string that it owns, and calls `free` on later."

Comment: @kaz see the examples in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68806946/65863).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard cross-platform equivalent would be to allocate/free a `wchar_t[]` buffer using `new[]`/`delete[]` (or, if absolutely needed, `malloc()`/`free()` to mirror the behavior of `_wcsdup()`), using `std::copy()` or `std::memcpy()` to copy characters from `wstring` into that buffer, eg:

```cpp
std::wstring w = wstring.str();
wchar_t* out = new wchar_t[w.size()+1];
std::copy(w.begin(), w.end(), out);
w[w.size()] = L'\0';
...
delete[] out;

/*
std::wstring w = wstring.str();
wchar_t* out = (wchar_t*) malloc((w.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
std::copy(w.begin(), w.end(), out);
w[w.size()] = L'\0';
...
free(out);
*/
```

```cpp
std::wstring w = wstring.str();
size_t size = w.size() + 1;
wchar_t* out = new wchar_t[size];
std::memcpy(out, w.c_str(), size * sizeof(wchar_t));
...
delete[] out;

/*
std::wstring w = wstring.str();
size_t size = (w.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
wchar_t* out = (wchar_t*) malloc(size);
std::memcpy(out, w.c_str(), size);
...
free(out);
*/
```

But, either way, since `str()` returns a `std::wstring` to begin with, you are better off simply sticking with `std::wstring` instead of using `wchar_t*` at all:

```cpp
std::wstring out = wstring.str();
```

You can use `out.c_str()` or `out.data()` if you ever need a `(const) wchar_t*`, such as when passing `out` to C-style functions that take null-terminated string pointers.

Comment: Great Approach. Thanks for this.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer using `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>` instead of calling `new[]` and `delete[]` myself...  You may need to call `get()` to pass the value to some functions, but that seems to be the only downside to me...

Comment: @fabian personally, I would use `std::vector<wchar_t>` before using `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t>`, but using `std::wstring` by itself would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way is to have a configuration system in your program which tells you what the platform has and doesn't have:

In some source file dedicated to portability, you have:

```
#if !HAVE_WCSDUP
wchar_t *wcsdup(const wchar_t *orig)
{
  #if HAVE_MICROSOFT_WCSDUP
    return _wcsdup(orig);
  #else
    size_t nwch = wcslen(orig) + 1;
    wchar_t *copy = wmalloc(nwch);
    if (copy)
      wmemcpy(copy, orig, nwch);
    return copy;
  #endif
}
#endif
```

In some header file (also included by the above), you have this:

```
#if !HAVE_WSCDUP
extern "C" wchar_t wcsdup(const wchar_t *);
#endif
```

to provide the missing declaration. A possible approach also is this. In the header file, you do:

```
#if HAVE_WCSDUP
// nothing to provide
#elif HAVE_MICROSOFT_WCSDUP
// just alias to the Microsoft one via #define
#define wcsdup _wcsdup
#else
// declare ours: provided in portability.cc
extern "C" wchar_t wcsdup(const wchar_t *);
#endif
```

Then in `portability.cc`:

```
#if !HAVE_WCSDUP && !HAVE_MICROSOFT_WCSDUP
wchar_t *wcsdup(const wchar_t *orig)
{
  size_t nwch = wcslen(orig) + 1;
  wchar_t *copy = wmalloc(nwch);
  if (copy)
    wmemcpy(copy, orig, nwch);
  return copy;
}
#endif
```

You need a build configuration system around you program to supply the values of these `HAVE_` constants. On some systems, a shell script can inspect the environment and throw them into a `config.h`. For some systems, you can have canned configurations; e.g. the configuration step for building on Windows might consist of copying a hand-maintained `config-msvc.h` to `config.h`. In `config-msvc.h` you have:

```
#define HAVE_MICROSOFT_WCSDUP 1
```

I'm assuming that you need a `malloc`-duplicated string due to communicating with some API that consumes one. Therefore in my answer I have refrained from pontificating about using C++ library features to solve the problem.

However, in C++ code we should probably be referring to the C functions as `std::wcslen` and so forth. Or `portability.cc` can just be `portability.c`, if it is providing missing C functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string needs to be passed to a function that expects to `free` it, you can use `malloc` and `memcpy`:

```
auto const ws = wstring.str();
auto const ptr = std::malloc(sizeof wchar_t * (ws.size() + 1));
std::memcpy(ptr, ws.c_str(), sizeof wchar_t * (ws.size() + 1));
// pass ptr to another function, or std::free(ptr)
```

The `+ 1` is to account for the null terminator, which is not included in `size()`.

Comment: Does that compile for you? I don't think `sizeof` can be applied to an unparenthesized type name: it's either `sizeof expr` or `sizeof (type)`. `expr` can have parentheses, but `(type)` cannot omit them.